# Unity 3D. Физическая анимация

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Я хочу сделать реалистичную анимацию, как в игре Mordhau. В этой игре анимация взаимодействует с резкими поворотами игрока, его ударами об противника и т.д. Каким образом можно реализовать это в Unity?
Вообще я не знаю как описать этот вид анимации. Мне просто не хочется делать ванильную анимацию, которая выглядит деревянной и проходящей через текстуры.

Comment: Это всё делается с помощью окна Animator в Unity. И то что вы говорите "физическую" а не "деревянную". Физическая это просто идеально реализованная деревянная анимация для множество объектов.

Comment: @Alt_F4 во-первых "физически правильная" анимация существует и не имеет ничего общего с "деревянной анимацией для множества объектов", называется такая штука Inverse Kinematics. Во-вторых, что значит "для множества объектов"?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker для множество значит ну допустим ты стреляешь у тебя анимация  и на руку и на патроны и на оружие и ещё многое другое. Я имел ввиду что если делать деревянную анимацию для множество объектов то анимация станет красивым и эти объекты дополнят друг друга

Comment: @Alt_F4 все предусмотреть невозможно, ваша идея не выдержит сложных сцен: персонаж, к примеру, взбирается по камням, будете под **каждый** камень всех размеров создавать отдельную анимацию? Без IK эту задачу не решить.

Comment: @Spasibo https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Спасибо. Можете ответить на данную тему. Я закреплю как верный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невозможно сделать отдельную анимацию под каждую возможную ситуацию в игре. Для таких вещей во всех известных лично мне движках есть [Inverse Kinematics(IK)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) анимация. Простыми словами, данная система двигает части объекта к заданной точке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем данное движение ограничивается рядом "законов" - constraint'ов, что позволяет тонко настроить "правильное" поведение анимации.

IK позволяет, к примеру, реагировать объект персонажа на неровную поверхность или лестницу под ногами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правда, такое осуществимо с помощью и IK и физики.